# Underlying failure after a SIGPIPE

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, signals

I am getting an error code 141 when running a bash script on a CI server that I cannot reproduce locally.

After some searching, it sounds that error 141 indicates a `PIPEFAIL`, and I have a

```
set -o pipefail
```

at the top of the script.

However, I would like to know what the underlying error code was that caused the pipe to fail. Is there a way to extract the error code of the failing command? Or do I need to restructure the script to not use pipes to get that?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is bash you might consider PIPESTATUS

```
command exit 1 | command exit 2 | command exit 3 | foobar; declare -p PIPESTATUS
```

After the warning that `foobar` is not found you should get the value of `PIPESTATUS`

```
 declare -a PIPESTATUS=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="127")
```

Answer (score 0):

141 is the value `$?` gets if a process exits due to signal 13, which on Linux is `SIGPIPE` (see [signal(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/signal.7.en.html)). That's what a process gets if it tries to write to a pipe with no readers. Usually you wouldn't see that return value, since the return status of a pipe is that of the last process in it. But with `pipefail` set, Bash returns the last *failing* value.

```
$ (echo x; sleep 1; echo y) | head -1 >/dev/null ; echo $?
0

$ set -o pipefail
$ (echo x; sleep 1; echo y) | head -1 >/dev/null ; echo $?
141
```

Comment: Why does the second example fail though? Which of the piped commands fail? I don't see any issues.